# Cannot "desynchronize" function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have created a javascript function that artificially "takes time" to work (around 2 or 3 seconds). It is just a long "for loop".
I want that function to not be synchronized with the others.
i mean that i would like that the function that finishes fast, and that is called at the end of script, i want its log to appear too soon.
I do not want to use : setTimeOut, fetch, filopen... that are already "black box" promises...
I mean can synchronous javascript become "asynchronous" if needed.

Please, what should i do ? i think i will have to use async and await.
My aim is not to use "promise" statement please. the aim is to desynchronise not to get any result value
here is the code :

```
var fullTime = function() {
                          var currentdate = new Date(); 
                          return (currentdate.getDate()+"/"+(currentdate.getMonth()+1)+"/" +
                          currentdate.getFullYear()+"-"+currentdate.getHours()+":"+
                          currentdate.getMinutes()+":"+currentdate.getSeconds()); 
                          };
  
var AfficherFullTime =  function(argEvent) {console.log(argEvent + " " + fullTime())  ; } ;
  
var processTakesTime = function () {
                             var i = 0 ;
                             const max = 6000000 ;
                              for (i=1;i<=max;i++) {
                                    if (i== max )
                                                     AfficherFullTime("loizAsynchrone > maximum value at ") ;
                                    else
                                                   { 
                                                   if (i == 1 ) 
                                                                AfficherFullTime("loizAsynchrone > maximum value at ") ;
                                                   else
                                                                fullTime();
                                                   
                                                   }
                              }
} ;
                          
                          
var testNoCallBack = function() {                                                                       
                                     processTakesTime();                    
                                    AfficherFullTime('first log');                                  
                                  };
                                  
testNoCallBack() ;
```

The result is :

```
loizAsynchrone > maximum value at........
loizAsynchrone > maximum value at............
first log ....................
```

And should be :

```
loizAsynchrone > maximum value at........
first log ....................
loizAsynchrone > maximum value at............
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [promise] and [async-await] if you don't want to use those?

Comment: "*I have created a javascript function that artificially "takes time" to work. It is just a long "for loop".*" - there's your problem. Don't write a synchronous loop when you want asynchronous behaviour. Use asynchronous functions in your code instead, i.e.  `setTimeout` to simulate wasting time.

Comment: The aim is for me not "to have to use" : setTimeOut, fetch, filopen... 
Can classic javascript, synchronous instruction become asynchronous because it is needed... for mutli task working
I know javascript is one thread working only, but by usinc async, is it possible to find a solution ?

Comment: No, it's not. You cannot use `async`/`await` without actually using asynchronous functions. If you need synchronous (cpu limited) code to run in the background, you need a separate worker thread.

Comment: ok, i have my answer. thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to "Bergi", who gave the answer.

**problem (asked by me):**
"The aim is for me not "to have to use" : setTimeOut, fetch, filopen... Can classic javascript, synchronous instruction become asynchronous because it is needed... for mutli task working I know javascript is one thread working only, but by usinc async, is it possible to find a solution ?"

**solution/ answer by Bergi :**
"No, it's not. You cannot use async/await without actually using asynchronous functions. If you need synchronous (cpu limited) code to run in the background, you need a separate worker thread"

Thank you Bergi